# TypeScript com React-navigation

Tags: javascript, typescript, react, react-native, react-navigation

estou com uma duvida em typar o prop Navigation de um componente funcional, meu codigo atualmente esta assim:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Container, Button, ButtonText } from './styles';
import { NavigationStackProp } from 'react-navigation-stack';


export default function Home({ navigation }: <NavigationStackProp>) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Auth')}>
        <ButtonText>Logout</ButtonText>
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Mas o Visual Studio esta dando alerta no Navigation:

> Property 'navigation' does not exist on type '() => any'.ts(2339) Como
>   corrijo isso?

Answer (score 1):

Tive a mesma duvida e consegui resolver fazendo uma interface e utilizando o NavigationStackProp ele irá mapear propriedades para dentro da função.

Exemplo da Interface:

```
interface iHomeProps {
  navigation: NavigationStackProp<any,any>
};
```

Como seu código deve ficar:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Container, Button, ButtonText } from './styles';
import { NavigationStackProp } from 'react-navigation-stack';

interface iHomeProps {
  navigation: NavigationStackProp<any,any>
};

export default function Home: React.FC<iHomeProps>({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Auth')}>
        <ButtonText>Logout</ButtonText>
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );

}
```